Apply style to all but last div
I am trying to apply a specific style to all divs for class within a div except for the last one. I've done this a few times, but for whatever reason it's not working like the others. Am I missing something? It's currently just applying the 24px bottom margin to all StyledDiv
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

&:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
`;

<div>
   <StyledDiv className='childDiv'>
       <p>Hello World 1</p>
   </StyledDiv>
   <StyledDiv className='childDiv'>
       <p>Hello World 2</p>
   </StyledDiv>
   <div>
       <p>Some other text and not a styled div</p>
   </div>
</div>


are you suggesting the last StyledDic should have the margin-bottom: 0? it's not the last child ... so, it won't

I am trying to accomplish setting the last div with className childDiv to margin-bottom: 0

yes, and I explained why your CSS is flawed

something like &:not(:has(~ .childDiv)) may help - but note, it depends on the "StyledDiv" having that class

That's it. Thank you. If you want to put that into an answer I'll mark it @JaromandaX

Since the <StyledDiv> is not the last child, you'll need to change the selector to check if the element has a subsequent <SyledDiv> sibling
Important Note: this depends on all <StyledDiv> sharing the class childDiv
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

&:not(:has(~ .childDiv)) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
`;

<div>
   <StyledDiv className='childDiv'>
       <p>Hello World 1</p>
   </StyledDiv>
   <StyledDiv className='childDiv'>
       <p>Hello World 2</p>
   </StyledDiv>
   <div>
       <p>Some other text and not a styled div</p>
   </div>
</div>

